# Hadoop distcp: what ports are used?

Tags: hadoop, networking, hdfs, distcp

If I want to use distCp on an on-prem hadoop cluster, so it can 'push' data to external cloud storage, what firewall considerations must be made in order to leverage this tool? What ports does the actual transfer of data take place on? Is it via SSH, and/or port 8020? I need to make sure network connectivity is provided for source to destination, but with the least amount of privileges ascribed to it. (i.e., only opening ports that are absolutely needed)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe SSH is used for the actual data transfer, other than you actually logging into the cluster and starting the command, for example.

At a minimum, it would be the RPC data-transfer ports for the NameNodes and Datanodes, so whatever you've configured for `fs.defaultFS`, `dfs.namenode.rpc-address` and `dfs.datanode.address`

Comment: Thanks. And what ports should be open within the GCP project to allow writes to GCS buckets

Comment: GCS doesn't need ports opened; it needs IAM roles, but this is not related to your original post, so I suggest creating new post specifically for GCP or DataProc